# Mi código en Laravel explota con una Undefined variable: cliente en la vista

Tags: php, laravel

Código del Controlador del Cliente

```
class ClienteControlador extends Controller
  {
    public function home(){

  $clientes=[2,'Lucian Rodriguez Plasencia',21,58531091];
   return view('Index',['clientes'=>$clientes]);
     }
  }
```

Código de la Ruta dirigida al Controlador

```
  Route::get('cliente','ClienteControlador@home');
```

Código del Model

```
   class cliente extends Model
   {
     protected $table="cliente";
      protected $fillable=['id','nombre','edad','movil'];
        }
```

Código de la Vista

```
       @section
       <table>
          <thead>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Edad</th>
          <th>Movil</th>
          </thead>
         <tr>
          @foreach($cliente as $f)
            <td>{{ $f->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $f->nombre }}</td>
            <td>{{ $f->edad }}</td>
            <td>{{ $f->movil }}</td>
     @endforeach
         </tr>
       </table>
      @endsection
```

No sé por qué me lanza ese error; estos pasos los seguí por un video tutorial y no funcionan.

Comment: Pues te recomiendo que vuelvas a ver el tutorial, porque lo estás usando un poco al revés. Primero, en el `return view(blabla` tienes comentado el array, y segundo el `foreach` es justo al revés... la traducción literal es: `paraCada($cliente como $f)`, es decir, para cada objeto que haya en `$cliente` lo almacenas en `$f` para poder usarlo, así que dentro del foreach deberías usar `$f->id`, no `$cliente->id`. Te recomiendo que repases un poco más la teoría de esa parte :)

Comment: Lo siento es que estaba haciendo pruebas pero lo tenia tal y como dices y explotaba de igual manera

Answer (score 1):

**Primer error**

Estas tratando de acceder a los valores de un array como si de un objeto se tratara lo cual claramente esta mal.

De forma resumida, como este array que presentas no tiene claves si no únicamente un conjunto de valores entonces en la vista debes imprimir sus valores por medio de su clave de esta forma:

```
{{ $variable[indice] }}

{{  $clientes[0] }} //daría el valor 2
```

Ahora si tratas de hacerlo por medio de un ciclo, entonces debería ser de esta forma:

```
@foreach($clientes as $cliente)
    {{ $cliente }}
@endforeach
```

De lo anterior se desprende el hecho de que no sea lógico que trates de acceder a la clave id de un array que **no** la contiene

**Segundo error**

El otro error que tienes es de sintaxis puesto que en el método mandas a `$clientes` y luego en la vista tratas de iterar a `$cliente` como notas no son lo mismo, la última no existe y por eso el error.

**EDICIÓN**

Te agrego un ejemplo de como construir una matriz de objetos e iterarlos en la vista con la sintaxis que buscas:

*Tu base de datos*

```
$clientes = [
                (object)[   "id" =>2,
                            "nombre" =>'Lucian Rodriguez Plasencia',
                            "clave" => 21,58531091
                        ],
                (object)[   "id" =>3,
                            "nombre" =>'Lucia',
                            "clave" => 21,58531091
                        ],
                        
            ];

  return view('playground', compact('clientes'));
```

*En tu vista*

```
@foreach ($clientes as $cliente)
    {{ $cliente->id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: pero eso no justifica que de un error de variable no definida

Comment: edito y te explico @LucianLopez

Comment: @LucianLopez revisa la edición y el ejemplo que te agregué

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores en tu codigo, lo ire poniendo para que te des cuenta de ello:

1. Controlador del Cliente:

- En esta parte tienes comentado `/*,['clientes'=>$clientes]*/` por lo cual, nunca se enviara la variable a la vista

2. Codigo de la Vista:

- Estas usando mal el `foreach`, lo que deberia ser es lo siguiente:

```
@foreach($clientes as $f)
   <td>{{ $f->id }}</td>
   <td>{{ $f->nombre }}</td>
   <td>{{ $f->edad }}</td>
   <td>{{ $f->movil }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Si descomentastes la primera parte entonces la "expresión_array" seria `clientes` con la "s". Ademas como en tu controlador solamente tienes `$clientes=[2,'Lucian Rodriguez Plasencia',21,58531091];`

No iterara porque `$clientes` no tiene una `clave`, como lo siguiente:

```
$clientes = [
    'id' => 2, 'nombre' => 'Lucian Rodriguez Plasencia', 
    'edad' => 21, 
    'movil' => 58531091
];
```

Comment: Todo lo que me dijiste lo corregi y sigue explotando dice que la variable $clientes de vista no esta definida

Comment: @LucianLopez en tu controlador le estas enviando `['clientes' => $clientes]` y en tu vista en el `foreach` esta como `foreach ( $clientes as $f )`?

Comment: Si, asi lo hacian en el tutorial. Pero si conoces otra forma mientras me funcione no habria ningun problema. Como tal tengo base de datos y todo pero como no me funcionan con datos estaticos para que meterme a sacarlos de la BD